# Display JSON array data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I might be making a silly mistake but I have this REST API output that i am consuming in UI through React and I am partially getting the output. When i console log, i get the output for ( testRows is data in AJAX -  this.setState({testRows: data});) :

```
this.state.testRows.Type as 'Application Performance'
```

but when i do this.state.testRows.Names[0] to print first value i.e. desc2, i face an error. What is the correct way to display or print array values of JSON in react?

```
{

"Names": [
"desc2",
"desc3"
],
"Result": 0,
"Type": "Application Performance",
"dateTime": [
"2016-07-26 20:35:55",
"2016-07-26 20:35:55"
 ]

}
```

ReactJS :

```
var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {

            testRows: []

        };
    },

    componentWillMount: function (event) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
            url: /details/3,
            success: function(data) {
                this.setState({testRows: data});
            }.bind(this),
            error:function(data) {
                alert("Data sending failed");
            }
        });
    },

    render: function() {

        console.log(this.state.testRows.Type); ~~ I get the output 
        console.log(this.state.testRows.Names[0]); ~~ Error

        return (

        );
    }
});

var element = document.getElementById('content');
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App), element);
```

Comment: Can you provide the source for your component that is attempting to render this data?

Comment: @JohnF. edited the code

Comment: what is the output of `this.state.testRows` if you log it in console? Can you make sure the data you are getting back from rest url indeed has the Names?

Comment: You currently have `testRows` as being initialized to array but it looks like based on your data that `testRows` is an object that contains a property `Names` that is an array. I'd change that .

Comment: `i face an error. ` Can you tell us what error/warning if any in console??

Comment: This is console output of testRows : {Names: Array[0], Result: 0, Type: "Application Performance",dateTime:Array[0]}

Comment: Can you directly go to the url in ajax in a browser tab and see if you get the data. I see that you get empty array for `names` and `dateTime`. Confirm if your api gives data as expected.

Comment: @Panther it says Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: @Panther I checked the API output in postman and in browser. It throws correct output

Comment: ok add this statement in the success of your ajax `console.log("1" + JSON.stringify(data))`. Add this to your render `console.log("2" + JSON.stringify(this.state.testRows))` and show us the output

Comment: @Panther
2{"Names":["desc2","desc3"],"Result":0,"Type":"Application Performance","dateTime":["2016-07-26 20:35:55","2016-07-26 20:35:55"]}
1{"Names":["desc2","desc3"],"Result":0,"Type":"Application Performance","dateTime":["2016-07-26 20:35:55","2016-07-26 20:35:55"]}

Comment: @Panther But when I do console.log(this.state.testRows.Names[1]); - I get  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Comment: @Panther I get the output ["desc2", "desc3"] when i do console.log(this.state.testRows.Names);
Cant i access the value through [0],[1] to access individual elements?

Comment: If(this.state.testRows.Names){
console.log("Won" + this.state.testRows.Names[0]);
}
Try this. This log should appear once your ajax is success.

Comment: @Panther Wondesc2

Comment: @Panther Thats strange to me. If i only put console.log(this.state.testRows.Names[0]); I get an error but if i put it under if clause as u said its throwing output

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to console log the `Names` from your render method.
Render method gets called immediately after the component is mounted, which means that your ajax has not completed by that time and so your state does not have `Names` and hence when you try to access an `undefined` error is thrown.

But after your ajax is completed and state is set, and when `render` is called again the `if` clause satisfies and your code works as the `names` is now available.

Comment: You should access `this.state.testRows.Names` only when it is available and to do that have an `if` clause to check if it is available